# why QOpenGLFunctions_2_0::initializeOpenGLFunctions is so slow on Mac 10.10?

Tags: qt, opengl

I need to create hundreds of objects which call `QOpenGLFunctions_2_0::initializeOpenGLFunctions()`. But I found that initializeOpenGLFunctions() was very slow when I built the qt app on Mac 10.10.

Details:

To reproduce this issue, I built the [Qt OpenGL example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html) on both Mac 10.10 and Mac 10.11. And I found that the one built on Mac 10.10 is 40 times slower than the one from 10.11. No matter I ran it on a 10.10 mac or a 10.11 mac.

To measure the time, I printed the timestamps in openglwindow.cpp

```
    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() << ":" << __LINE__;
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    qDebug() << QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch() << ":" << __LINE__;
    initialize();
```

and the outputs are:

```
// built on Mac 10.11
1503009550512 : 88
1503009550514 : 90

// built on Mac 10.10 (40 times slower)
1503009508921 : 88
1503009509007 : 90
```

More details of the build environments:

```
Qt 5.6.2

MacOS 10.11.6
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix

Mac 10.10.
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please use QElapsedTimer for such measurements, and try with Qt 5.9. If the regression is still there, open a bug report.

Comment: @peppe, thanks. Qt 5.9.1 doesn't have this issue. Will report this bug.